# Machine-readable corpus of Russian words

Tags: лингвистика

For academic reasons I am interested in machine-readable information about Russian words.

For example, nouns with attached information about

- grammatical gender
- declension
- alive or not
- etc...

or verbs with

- conjugation
- valency

Do you know about any freely available corpus I could use without having to scrap the data from online sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also have a look to project OpenCorpora at http://opencorpora.org/

Answer (score 2):

ruscorpora.ru - the main corpus of Russian language. Its information is in Russian, though.